# arbitrary large finite sums of an uncountable set.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How to prove that given an uncountable subset $A$ of $R^+$, there exits a finite number of elements in A whose sum is arbitrarily large?

Comment: Does $R^+$ denote the positive reals?

Comment: yes. positive reals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: Let $I_0=(1,\to)$, and for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $I_n=\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right]$. $\{I_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is countable, and $A$ is uncountable, so there must be some $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $A\cap I_{n_0}$ is uncountable. Show that $A\cap I_{n_0}$ has finite subsets with arbitrarily large sums.

Comment: sorry. I dont understand. Why $A \cap I_{n_{0}}$ should have finite finite sunsets with arbitrary cardinality?

Comment: @GArunkumar: Because it’s infinite, and every element of it is greater than $\frac1{n+1}$. If you take a subset $F$ of $A\cap I_{n_0}$ that contains $k$ elements, and each of those $k$ elements is greater than $\frac1{n+1}$, then the sum of the elements of $F$ is greater than ... what?

Comment: ya. by choose large k, we can make $k\frac{1}{n+1}$ as large as possible.thanks.

Comment: @GArunkumar: That’s right; now you’ve got it.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A_n = \{x \in A : x > \frac 1n\}$.  Then at least one set $A_n$ is infinite because...

Comment: please complete the argument.

Comment: ...if every $A_n$ were finite, $A$ would have to be...

Comment: one $A_n$ will be infinite. but from this what is the conclusion. can you please explain me more clearly

Comment: thanks. I understand your point. there exist finite subset $A_n$ which sum can be made large.

Comment: How does the conclusion that there exists a finite subset whose sum can be made large follow from showing that at least one $A_n$ is infinite?