# A countability problem of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

I am having a really hard time coming up with a proof for this problem. For every finite set $F\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, let $\Sigma(F)$ denote the sum of the numbers in $F.(\Sigma(\emptyset)=0)$. Show that if $S\subseteq (0,+\infty)$ and $\Sigma(F)\leq100$ for every finite set $F \subseteq S$, then $S$ is finite or countable. I can't see why $S$ could be countable but not uncountable. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: I think this was asked an uncountable number of times on the site, in several and many variables.

Comment: I did search through the questions but did not find a similar one. I'll try looking again.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359669/arbitrary-large-finite-sums-of-an-uncountable-set) are [some](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20661/the-sum-of-an-uncountable-number-of-positive-numbers) examples of [similar](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20661/the-sum-of-an-uncountable-number-of-positive-numbers). As for the possibility that $S$ is countable, pick any convergent series whose limit is $\leq 100$.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I think I have a better idea on how to approach the problem now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $S_n=\{s\in S\mid s>\frac{1}{n}\}$. How many elements can be in $S_n$ if $\sum(F)<100$ for all finite $F\subseteq S$?

Answer (score -2):

$S=\{1,1/2,1/4,1/8,1/16,\ldots\}$ is an example of a countably infinite set that meets the requirements.

Comment: And how should this be an answer to the question?

Comment: @egreg OP said "I can't see why $S$ could be countable but not uncountable", so I gave an example.

Comment: You are misreading that part of the question, @ChrisCulter. The question isn't "are there examples of countably infinite $S$," but why can there exist such infinite sets but not uncountably infinite sets.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sure, that's the original prompt given to fishy. I guess I tried too hard to interpret fishy's question in a way that isn't a restatement of the original prompt.